# A question on the dual relationship between the regressive product and the exterior product

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

I am trying to understand the following sentence, which I came across in a book:

> The underlying beauty of the *Ausdehnungslehre* is due to this symmetry [the duality between the regressive and exterior product], which in turn is due to the fact that linear spaces of $m$-elements and linear spaces of $(n-m)$-elements have the same dimension...

According to the book, this is related to the dual nature of the regressive and exterior products:

> For example, the exterior product of $m$ 1-elements is an $m$-element. The dual to this is that the regressive product of $m$ $(n-1)$-elements is an $(n-m)$-element.

**What exactly is confusing about the above?**

1) How do linear spaces of $m$-elements and linear spaces of $(n-m)$-elements have the same dimension? Actually, what is meant by dimension here? I understand dimension to be the number of $m$-elements necessary to build an object of a particular space - i.e. the grade of the object. Is this correct? With this view, $(n-m) \neq m$.

2) I don't see how the fact that the result of the regressive product when applied to $m$ $n-1$ elements is an $(n-m)$-element makes it the dual of the exterior product...

3) How is duality akin to symmetry? I am unable to appreciate the beauty in the duality between two operators.

Comment: This seems like a potentially old and outdated book; in particular I have never heard the term "regressive product" before. You should find a more modern reference. This linear-space thing is a statement about the dimensions of Grassmannians (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to answer this in the language of geometric algebra (because I can't seem to translate it into Grassmann algebra right).

---

A $k$-blade is the exterior product of $k$ linearly independent vectors.  In geometric algebra, the dual $A^*$ is the $(n-k)$-blade such that $A \wedge A^* = |A|^2I$ (but we're not particularly interested in that constant, $|A|^2$, here), where $I$ is called the unit pseudoscalar -- the highest grade element of our $n$-space.  Thus we can consider this "dual" to be the part of $I$ which doesn't "contain" any of $A$.

The "regressive product" seems to be what I've heard called the "meet" of blades.  The meet $M=A \vee B$ (which if you learn Geometric Algebra has the simple formula $A \vee B = A^* \cdot B$) is the blade of largest grade such that $A=M \wedge A'$ and $B=B' \wedge M$.  Thus the regressive product is the part of $A$ and $B$ "contained" by both $A$ and $B$.

You'll want to note that in $\Bbb G^n$, there are [$\binom{n}{k}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) orthogonal unit $k$-blades. Thus each $k$-space (the subspace of elements of grade $k$) has the same dimension as $(n-k)$-space.  Where *dimension* here means the same thing it does in linear algebra: it's the maximum number of linearly independent "basis blades" the any $k$-space can hold -- this is **distinct** from the *grade* of a $k$-space/ $k$-blade.  For example, take our space to be $\Bbb G^4$.  This is the space of scalars, vectors, 2-blades, 3-blades, 4-blades, and the sums of these objects.  In this space there are $\binom 42=6$ basis 2-blades -- usually they are called $e_1 \wedge e_2, e_1 \wedge e_3, e_1 \wedge e_4, e_2 \wedge e_3, e_2 \wedge e_4, $ and $e_3 \wedge e_4$ -- and thus the **dimension** of the subspace formed by the span of these basis blade is **$6$**.  However each element of the subspace is of **grade $2$**.

The fact that each $k$-space then has the same dimension as $(n-k)$-space is really the important part for understanding what your book is saying:

What this section of your book is saying is that: $ (\wedge^m\ V)^* = \vee^m\ V^*$ and (by the fact that the dual of the dual of an element is that same element up to sign) likewise $(\vee^m\ V)^* = \wedge^m\ V^*$.  That is $(A \wedge B)^*=A^* \vee B^*$.  So the *smallest* blade "containing" $A$ & $B$ is dual to the *largest* blade "contained" by both the dual of $A$ and the dual of $B$.

Because in geometric algebra we have a very simple formula for finding the dual of a blade (for reference it's $A^* = AI^{-1}$), we could theoretically represent any exterior product by regressive products (AKA meets) and vice versa.  I think this rather unexpected and potentially powerful result is what this author is calling the "beauty" of this relation.

---

I don't know if any of this has made any sense to you, so just comment below if you still have questions.

Comment: You're right. The "regressive product" in the book I was reading is the same as the "meet" in GA. Your answer is helpful, and it answers some of my more basic questions right away. If I have more, I will be sure to ask. Right now though, my question for you is this: I see you are engaged in the same task I am -- self-learning GA -- would you recommend any textbooks as being particularly helpful for you? The "book" we keep referring to in the question is [this one here](https://sites.google.com/site/grassmannalgebra/thegrassmannalgebrabook).

Comment: @user89 If by GA you mean Grassmann algebra, then I'm *not* learning it.  I just happen to know a little about it, because it is encompassed by Clifford algebra.  I am in fact studying geometric algebra -- which is the real-valued, geometrically-interpreted version of Clifford algebra.  If geometric algebra is what you meant by GA, then I'd have to know where you are in your math education and what your interests in learning it are before I could recommend a book.

Comment: @user89 If you are interested in Grassmann algebra, then [this book](http://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/Kayed/eBooksLectureNotes/Linear_Algebra_via_Exterior_Products_By_Sergei_Winitzki.pdf) caught my eye the other day.  I haven't had a chance to look it over, yet -- but from it's table of contents it looks pretty interesting.

Comment: Ah, I meant Geometric Algebra! In terms of my math education, well, I have finished linear algebra, multivariable calculus, ODEs and a bit of PDEs. I am interested in applying GA to general problems in physics.

Comment: Well the standard physics text is Doran and Lasenby's *Geometric Algebra for Physicists*.  I find it a little terse in places, but an invaluable book just by the range of topics it covers.  For mechanics there's David Hestenes' *New Foundations for Classical Mechanics* -- I haven't actually read through very much of it, but it seems pretty good.  For E&M there's John Arthur's *Understanding Geometric Algebra for Electromagnetic Theory*.  I've found this one to be a wonderful book that's given me a lot of insight into E&M (which I just didn't get in my first class on it).

Comment: From a purely mathematical POV, you can't really go wrong with Alan Macdonald's books on geometric algebra and geometric calculus.  They're pretty basic and go over a lot of linear algebra and vector calculus, as well -- but you'll appreciate how basic they are, when you find that after going through them every other GA book you read is much more readable.  If you're interested in geometry, there's Calvet's *Treatise of Plane Geometry Through Geometric Algebra* -- it's a little harder than you'd think for a book on mostly Euclidean geometry.

Comment: And finally, when you're up to it (I'm not yet), there's Sobczyk's *New Foundations in Mathematics: The Geometric Concept of Number* which goes from basics like modular arithmetic all the way up to differential geometry mostly in the language of geometric algebra.  That's about all the books I know of that aren't a complete waste of time (*cough*Snygg*cough*).

Comment: Hey, thanks! I think then that for the moment, I'll check out Alan Macdonald's books.

Comment: Good luck.  If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.  I've started answering questions on here, but you'll probably also get some answered by Muphrid and Rschwieb (who both know a LOT more than I do).

Comment: As a matter of interest, I would also recommend Hestenes and Sobczyk's *Clifford Algebra to Geometric Calculus*.  It helps bridge the gap between the more distant approaches to geometric algebra (the book makes heavy use of the concept of "extensors," suggesting to me that Hestenes was well aware of Rota and previous work). It has some good, rigorous stuff on linear algebra, proving the Cayley-Hamilton theorem in a novel way, and it's my fundamental reference for differential geometry using GA and vector manifolds.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently also studying Grassmann algebra. I'm a graphics & game programmer, not a mathematician, so I apologize for using wrong terminology and mistakes.

The way I see it:

- "dimension" is the minimum set of vectors of a vectorspace that span the entire space. This set is called a basis. Spanning means we can build each vector in the vectorspace from a unique linear combination of the basis vectors.
- so if we have an N-dimensional vectorspace, we need exactly N vectors to span the space.

To explain the duality between the exterior and regressive product, consider the following example:

Suppose we have a 4D linear space V spanned by basis vectors {e1,e2,e3,e4}. This means that every element in V can be uniquely written as a1*e1 + a2*e2 + a3*e3 + a4*e4 for scalars {a1,a2,a3,a4}

When we add a Grassmann algebra ˄(V) to V, we get several subspaces from combining the vectors using the exterior aka wedge ˄ product:

- the sub-space of 0-elements (scalars, blades of grade 0) has dimension 1: the basis {1} spans all other scalars.
- the sub-space of 1-elements (vectors, blades of grade 1) has dimension 4: the basis is  {e1,e2,e3,e4}, the same one as our 4D vectorspace we started with
- the sub-space of 2-elements (bi-vectors, blades of grade 2) has dimension 6: the basis is {e1˄e2, e1˄e3, e1˄e4, e2˄e3, e2˄e4, e3˄e4} := {e12, e13, e14, e23, e24, e34}. Every bivector can be build from a linear combination of bivectors in this basis
- the sub-space of 3-elements (tri-vectors, blades of grade 3, aka 4D anti-vectors) has dimension 4: the basis is {e1˄e2˄e3, e1˄e2˄e4, e1˄e3˄e4, e2˄e3˄e4} := {e123, e124, e134, e234}.
- the sub-space of 4-elements (quad-vectors, blades of maximum grade 4, aka 4D pseudo-scalars or anti-scalars) has dimension 1: the basis is {e1˄e2˄e3˄e4} := {e1234} := {I}.

Notice the dimensions of these sub-spaces: 1 4 6 4 1

In general, for an N-dimensional vector-space, the dimensions of the sub-spaces formed by the exterior products of vectors are found in the Nth row of a Pascal triangle, or can be computed using the binomial.

We clearly see a symmetry here! Instead of defining an exterior product that works on vectors, we can just as well define a regressive product that works on anti-vectors.

We first define a complementary "anti-basis" {ē1,ē2,ē3,ē4} (note that we are not talking about orthogonality here, we need no metric at all).

We define the complements ~ei = ēi in such a way the ei ˄ (ēi) = e1˄e2˄e3˄e4 = I

- ē1 = +e2˄e3˄e4 because e1 ˄ (ē1) = e1˄(+e2˄e3˄e4) = e1˄e2˄e3˄e4 (no swaps needed)
- ē2 = -e1˄e3˄e4 because e2 ˄ (ē2) = e2˄(-e1˄e3˄e4) = e1˄e2˄e3˄e4 (1 swap e2 <-> e1 needed)
- ē3 = +e1˄e2˄e4 because e3 ˄ (ē3) = e3˄(+e1˄e2˄e4) = e1˄e2˄e3˄e4 (2 swaps e3 <-> e1 <-> e2 needed)
- ē4 = -e1˄e2˄e3 because e4 ˄ (ē4) = e4˄(-e1˄e2˄e3) = e1˄e2˄e3˄e4 (3 swaps e4 <-> e1 <-> e2 <-> e3 needed)

Note that ~1 = I and ~I = 1 because 1 ^ I = 1 and I ^ 1 = I. So the complement of the unit-scalar is the unit anti-scalar and vice-versa. They are ‘dual’ under complement, just like Boolean algebra. Grassmann didn't make a difference between pseudo-scalars and scalars, he even didn't make a notational difference between the exterior and regressive products.

We define the regressive product ˅ to form new "anti-sub-spaces" using {ē1,ē2,ē3,ē4} as a "anti-basis":

- the 1D anti-sub-space anti-scalars: basis {I} = {~1}
- the 4D anti-sub-space anti-vectors: basis {ē1,ē2,ē3,ē4}
- the 6D anti-sub-space anti-bivectors: basis {ē1˅ē2, ē1˅ē3, ē1˅ē4, ē2˅ē3, ē2˅ē4, ē3˅ē4} = {ē12, ē13, ē14, ē23, ē24, ē34}.
- the 4D anti-sub-space of anti-tri-vectors: basis {ē1˅ē2˅ē3, ē1˅ē2˅ē4, ē1˅ē3˅ē4, ē2˅ē3˅ē4} = {ē123, ē124, ē134, ē234}
- the 1D anti-sub-space of scalars: basis {1}

This is “dual” in the sense that we just replaced ˄ by ˅, e by ē, 1 by I

The dual of a blade with grade M (e.g. e123 with grade 3) maps to an anti-blade (ē123 = e4) with “anti-grade” M or grade N-M (4-1 = 1)

The regressive product can be written using the exterior product by just using the complement operator ~: for any blades x and y, we have something that looks like the De Morgan Law:

~(x˄y) = (~x) ˅ (~y) at least upto a sign I think

The regressive product corresponds to the ‘meet’ (“intersection”) from geometric algebra I guess (I'm first tackling Grassmann before starting with GA), for example:

```
 (e123) ˅ (e234) 
 = 
 ~~((e123) ˅ (e234)) 
 = 
 ~(~e123 ˄ ~e234) 
 = 
 ~(e4 ˄ -e1)
 =
 -~e41
 =
 e23
```

which indeed is what e123 and e234 have in common

The interior product can also be defined as

x * y = x ˅ ~y

Comment: That is a useful way to think about it.  In case you were wondering, here's [a tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format your answers a little nicer.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial!